# Pulse animation with Leaflet has weird behaviour [GIF included]

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I want to make a pulse animation on a marker with Leaflet but I am getting a very weird behaviour.

**CSS**

```
.mapbox-marker {
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.animate {
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-animation: pulsate 30s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; 
    opacity: 0.0
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1); opacity: 0.0;}
50% {opacity: 1.0;}
100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.0;}
}
```

**This is my marker**

```
myCircleMarker = L.CircleMarker.extend({options: {
  radius: currentRadius,
  stroke: false,
  fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  clickable: false,
  className: 'mapbox-marker animate'
}});
```

**When i add my markers**

```
function addMarkersBatch(positions) {
    var markers = []
    positions.forEach(function(position) {
        var marker = new myCircleMarker(position);
        marker.setRadius(currentRadius*1.8);
        marker.setStyle({fillColor: "#fe5928"});
        map.addLayer(marker);
        markers.push(marker);
    });
}
```

The animation is as expected, but it comes with a very weird marker behavior. I just want the marker to scale on the map position, but it is moving across the screen while scaling.

[image: The weird behaviour]

Hope anyone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the fix was quite easy. i just have to set the `transform-origin` to center

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.0, 0.0); 
        opacity: 0.0;
        transform-origin:center;
    }
    1% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5); 
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    5% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); 
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.4, 0.4); 
        opacity: 0.0;
    }
}
```